# help with ancient coin design

Tags: modeling, texturing

can somebody help me to achieve making a similar ancient coin shown in the figure? Been doing it for days but cannot achieve the right results.

Thank you.

[image]

Comment: it would be nice if you have showed us what you tried. There are - as nearly always - a lot of ways to do that. e.g. normal maps, image texture, displace modifier, modelling. i would recommend watching some beginner tutorials about normals maps (of course this depends on the coins size to the render size)

Comment: Especially if you have assets already, like the heads/tails textures, that would help... In addition to screenshots, maybe you could pack your textures into your file (menu File > External Data > Pack all and save) then upload it on [blend-exchange.com](https://blend-exchange.com/) and share the link with us here.

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to know where you're struggling. You could create a cylinder and unwrap it (*Cylinder Project* for the sides, simple *Unwrap* for the top and bottom):

[image]

Then use the image of one of these coins (I had to blur it a bit) in the *Base Color* of the *Principled BSDF*, and also make a normal map from it and plug it into the *Normal* input of the *Principled*. Put the *Metallic* value at 1, decrease the *Roughness* value:

[image]

To deform the coin you can do it in *Sculpt* mode:

[image]